# Manipulating search event

Tags: plugin-development, search, events, api

Looking at a means to perform subqueries against certain searches in the back-end of the Craft CMS eg for searches against particular sections within Admin > Entries.

Looking into this it seems like the `SearchEvent` event might be best, and specifically `EVENT_BEFORE_SEARCH`. Was hoping can pass an array of specific elementIds into the event to tighten up the number of results returned but that doesn't seem to be working.

Example code:

```
  Event::on(
    Search::class,
    Search::EVENT_BEFORE_SEARCH,
    function (SearchEvent $event) {
      $sender = $event->sender;
      $sectionId = $elementQuery->sectionId;
      if ($sectionId == [4]) {
        $event->setElementIds($elementIdsArray); // eg [123,455], etc
      }

  });
```

However this is ignore and the usual search takes place.
Can anyone advise the best way to limit back-end searches to certain elementIds?

Cheers,

Cole

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code – maybe those just snuck in when you posted the code here, but right now the hook can't work correctly:

- `$elementQuery` is undefined – did you mean `$event->elementQuery`?
- `$elementIdsArray` is also not defined.
- Make sure you're importing the correct `Search` class (`craft\services\Search`).

Besides that, I don't think the `SearchEvent::setElementIds` function is intended to set element IDs to be used for the query. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/services/Search.php#L275-L282), the `SearchEvent` created for this hook is not saved as a variable and the method doesn't check if you've set any element IDs on the event:

```php
// Fire a 'beforeSearch' event
if ($this->hasEventHandlers(self::EVENT_BEFORE_SEARCH)) {
    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_SEARCH, new SearchEvent([
        'elementQuery' => $elementQuery,
        'query' => $searchQuery,
        'siteId' => $siteId,
    ]));
}
```

If you set the element IDs on the element query itself, the hook starts working correctly:

```php
use craft\services\Search;
use craft\events\SearchEvent;

Event::on(
    Search::class,
    Search::EVENT_BEFORE_SEARCH,
    function (SearchEvent $event) {
        $elementQuery = $event->elementQuery;
        $elementQuery->id([123, 455]);
    }
);
```

Now the last thing to check is if your condition is failing for some reason. A simple way to test this is to put a [Craft::dd](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft.html#method-dd) statement in there. Then go to Admin -> Entries in the backend, open the devtools in your browser and execute a search. Look for the search request executed by JavaScript, open it and look at the `Response` tab. There you can see the dumped value.